# How to sum a function in excel?

Tags: excel-formula

I want to sum this function up:

```
=I3*(A3*0.014+0.25)+I4*(A4*0.014+0.25)+I5*(A5*0.014+0.25)+....
```

But I don't know which function to use to sum everything to one. That doesn't work unfortunately

```
=SUM(I3:I9)*(SUM(A3:A9)*0.014+0.25)
```

Comment: sorry for the noob question (I don't know where else to go to ask this nooby question)

Comment: what is `(A3*0,014+0,25)`?  it will simplfy to `(0,14,25)` not sure what excel is supposed to do with that.

Comment: Sorry for that @ScottCraner (I'm from Germany and we write like that) So it should be I3*(A3*0.014+0.25)+I4*(A4*0.014+0.25)+I5*(A5*0.014+0.25)

Comment: ahh, I should have known.  sorry.  give me a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(I3:I9 * (A3:A9 * 0.014 + 0.25))
```